# How to allocate a closure-function on the call stack?

Tags: ats

When using higher-order functions like list_map, one needs to build closure-functions and pass them as arguments. Afterwards, the built closures become garbage. Is there a way to build such closure-functions on the call stack (so that they are automatically freed after the call)?

Answer (score 1):

As is specified in the [tutorial](http://ats-lang.sourceforge.net/DOCUMENT/INT2PROGINATS/HTML/HTMLTOC/x3475.html), you can use the following syntax:

```
var bar = lam@ (): int => x * y
```